# MySQL not updating a row (zero row(s) affected)

Tags: mysql, update

I cannot figure out why MySQL 5.6.25 will not update an existing row:

```
SELECT
  lcl_booking.file_number_id,
  lcl_booking.entered_datetime,
  lcl_booking.modified_datetime
FROM lcl_booking
WHERE lcl_booking.file_number_id = 197467;
```

yields:

```
file_number_id entered_datetime     modified_datetime
197467         2015-06-26 15:26:44  2015-07-08 10:39:15
```

Now, I do this:

```
UPDATE lcl_booking SET
  modified_datetime = "2015-07-21 10:54:04"
WHERE file_number_id = 197467;
```

returns:

```
1 queries executed, 1 success, 0 errors, 0 warnings

Query: UPDATE lcl_booking SET modified_datetime = "2015-07-21 10:54:04" WHERE file_number_id = 197467

0 row(s) affected

Execution Time : 0.019 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0.019 sec
```

and....

```
SELECT
  lcl_booking.file_number_id,
  lcl_booking.entered_datetime,
  lcl_booking.modified_datetime
FROM lcl_booking
WHERE lcl_booking.file_number_id = 197467;
```

yields:

```
file_number_id entered_datetime     modified_datetime
197467         2015-06-26 15:26:44  2015-07-08 10:39:15
```

Here is the table (minus a bunch of columns)

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE lcl_booking;

CREATE TABLE `lcl_booking` (
  `file_number_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `entered_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`file_number_id`),
KEY `lcl_booking_fk1` (`file_number_id`),
CONSTRAINT `lcl_booking_fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`file_number_id`) REFERENCES `lcl_file_number` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='LCL Booking Header';
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are there any triggers on the table?

Comment: Yep, and that is the problem!!! Someone added a trigger recently - didn't bother to run it by us DBAs first. A flogging shall be held this evening....

Comment: Will a flogging be done as well to the dba who gives permissions to add triggers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an undocumented trigger that was causing the problem.